# for loop initial declarations are only allowed in c99 or c11 mode

Tags: c

¿Cómo resuelvo el siguiente error?

> [Error] 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode

(Uso el compilador de C: **Dev++**).

Comment: ¿Solucionó mi respuesta tu pregunta? Márcala como correcta si fue así o déjame un comentario en mi respuesta si tienes cualquier otra duda.

Answer (score 6):

A partir del [estándar C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) se puede inicializar una variable contadora en el interior del bucle `for` para facilitar la lectura y delimitar su ámbito, pero si no se activa la compatibilidad con dicho estándar no se podrá utilizar esta funcionalidad.

Por lo que un bucle en el que se define y usa la variable en el mismo `for`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { ... }
```

Deberás cambiarlo por una definición previa y posterior uso de la variable en el `for`:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) { ... }
```

O bien deberemos activar la compatibilidad en el compilador usando el siguiente modificador la configuración de parámetros adicionales (si es `gcc`/`MinGW GCC`) en "Tools" > "Compiler Options" > "Add the following commands when calling the compiler":

```
-std=c99
```